# AutoIncrement Integer Column,Guid or PGuid, which to choose?

Tags: database, database-design, data, globals

Guid has been a Global Unique Identification. Why does "PGuid" (Global Unique Identification) appear?

1) Is Guid ***NOT PERMENT*** for unique? (I sometimes wonder whether Guid is REALLY PERMENT generator in .NET or Java)

2) Is "PGuid" ***just for "easy to read with namespace"?*** In what kinds of situations can we choose "Pguid" instead of "Guid" (Please offer some MOST DIFFERENCES examples).

3) Since we can use integer column in SQL or in most of db as a unique identifier, ***why Guid or Pguid?*** Are there any reasonable things for them?

It would be very nice if you can list each item and explain it in detailled sitations.

Reguards!

PS: I wanna add "Guid" or "Pguid" as a tag for my question, however I didn't find it. Anyone helps to apply it onto my question?

Comment: what context did you get PGUID from?

Comment: From https://wiki.regn.net/wiki/PGUID I know what PGuid is, however I don't understand what it really means and how and where to apply it... Just as what my questions mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points:

1. [PGUID](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_PGUID.html) may stand for **Pointer** to the GUID, not *Permanent* GUID. This is a pointer to the beginning of the memory block, where GUID is.
2. If you really meant [Persistent Identifiers](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Q5TkjgRll9gC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=persistent%20guid&source=bl&ots=-VJBkwDCVv&sig=_2CJ8gFtVLKiaWor-DAcMIt9xqQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMI6ImD8q2XyQIVSA0sCh0LUQ8k#v=onepage&q=persistent%20guid&f=false), then the difference can be seen as follows. ISBN can serve as a persistent identifier for the book because the book will forever have the same ISBN. If you add database entry about this book, make a mistake, delete an entry and readd again, guid will change. Persistent id will not.

Comment: Sorry, but please see this: https://wiki.regn.net/wiki/PGUID.

Comment: @CA55CE37 Can you update the link, please? I get NonExistent domain error. I cannot resolve domain regn.net from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 database, usually an auto incrementing number is fine as they are easy to implement and maintain.  The index on the primary key will not fragment over time because the numbers are nice and sequential.  So, there is very little index maintenance needed.  Additionally, storing a number should be smaller than a GUID as usually an INT in SQL Server only takes 4 bytes of storage.

However, GUIDs can be used when you have to replicate records from several databases into a master database.  The number "10" may be unique for that 1 database, but across several databases, that scheme will not work as those databases may also have a record "10".  So, GUIDs are used.  Then each record is unique.  With GUIDs the storage size is greater and you will have maintain the index (rebuild, etc.) with greater frequency then using a straight up integer.  There are ways to make "sequential" GUIDs to make the maintenance easier.